# Codeigniter Cost Function - No errors but not calculating

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function, codeigniter

i receive no SQL errors with this function built in codeigniter but i'm trying to calculate the zone difference between two form inputs passed as parameters. Could anyone see a problem with this function??

```
function stationcost($station1,$station2)
{

    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('station_zone.Zone-sz2.Zone AS Zone' , false)->from('station_zone')->join('station_zone AS sz2','sz2.Station', $station2)->where('station_zone.Station',$station1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();


    $this->db->select('Cost')->from('zone_cost')->where('Zone_Diff', $Q->row()->Zone_Diff);


    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data = $row->Cost;
            return $data;
        }

    } 
}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you verify this statement: $Q->row()->Zone_Diff, is returning content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your query

   ```
   $this->db->select('station_zone.Zone-sz2.Zone AS Zone' , false)
   ->from('station_zone')
   ->join('station_zone AS sz2','sz2.Station', $station2)
   ->where('station_zone.Station',$station1);
   $Q = $this->db->get();
   ```

   actually returns something. Try it first in phpmyadmin or similar tools for example, or build it manually and pass it to the `$this->db->query($sql)` method for example

   Also, you're building the join() wrong, mightbe:

   ```
   join('station_zone As sz2','sz2.Station = '.$station2)
   ```

   I think, it's not clear where $station2 comes from and which tables you want to join... Third parameter in join() should be the join type, like "left" for. ex. See [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

   Even the select() portion looks awkard, I see three dots there did you try running `$this->db->last_query();` to see how the query string looks like?
   I can't really figure it out so far...
2. In this second query:

   ```
   $this->db->select('Cost')
   ->from('zone_cost')
   ->where('Zone_Diff', $Q->row()->Zone_Diff);
   ```

   You ask for a `$Q->row()->Zone_Diff` which I can't see where is fetched...not in the previous query, it seems
3. Last, here:

   ```
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
           $data = $row->Cost;
           return $data;
       }

   }
   ```

You're overwriting the $data variable in the loop...No, you're returning just after the first passage! you should do:

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
       $data[] = $row->Cost;
    }
    return $data;
```

**UPDATE:**

You're saying your query works in phpmyadmin, so why not just doing:

```
$sql = "SELECT station_zone.Zone-sz2.Zone AS Zone FROM station_zone JOIN station_zone AS sz2 ON sz2.Station=? WHERE station_zone.Station=?";
$Q = $this->db->query($sql, array($station1,$station2));
```

and see if that works? Sometimes AR makes things more complicated when you need to start avoiding protection of identifiers and so on. A query like the above is still safe against injection because uses query bindings, and is 10 times easier than building with AR.

Withouth seeing the db schema, I stil find it foggy to understand why the JOIN and why operating only on a table and itself as alias...but I answered in wrong times of the day (night and this morning :)), so it just might be me. Which are the tables and how are they structured?

Comment: SELECT
station_zone.Zone-sz2.Zone 
AS Zone
FROM station_zone
JOIN station_zone AS sz2 ON sz2.Station=('station1')
WHERE station_zone.Station=('station2') works in phpmyadmin

Comment: $station1 comes from form input in the controller and passed as variables.

Comment: the select is awkward because it is trying to subtract the zone from $station2 - $station1 while first finding the zone difference in the zone_cost table...

Comment: yeah, I see now, but isn't station_zone alias to sz2? are you substracting the same field? And where are you substracting the 2 params? As a personal advice, when dealing with complex queries, first do it manually and then translate it with AR, beacuse the latter sometimes might become confusing and overcomplicated.

Comment: the manual query just results in a blank page :( i've tried alternatives but hmm

Comment: I made a small typo (forgot the last parenthesis). Don't you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: yes no errors but if i print_r:: CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #9 [result_id] => Resource id #26 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [row_data] => ) 1CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #9 [result_id] => Resource id #28 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [row_data] => ) 1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your IF and Foreach Statement... You need to use array_push to add to your $data variable since it is defined as an array. Also, your return statement breaks out of the function. Meaning your foreach only runs once. You need to move your return statment outside of the foreach statement so that it waits to return $data only once the foreach is complete.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    { 
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        { 
            array_push($data,$row->Cost); 

        } 
         return $data;

    }
```